# Javascript loop for 12 elements from html ->> Memo game

Tags: javascript, html, memory

I need to creat 2 loops for memo game:

First loop for var k elements and second for addeventlisteners:

```js
var c0 = document.getElementById('k0');
var c1 = document.getElementById('k1');
var c2 = document.getElementById('k2');
var c3 = document.getElementById('k3');
var c4 = document.getElementById('k4');
var c5 = document.getElementById('k5');
var c6 = document.getElementById('k6');
var c7 = document.getElementById('k7');
var c8 = document.getElementById('k8');
var c9 = document.getElementById('k9');
var c10 = document.getElementById('k10');
var c11 = document.getElementById('k11');

c0.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(0);});
c1.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(1);});
c2.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(2);});
c3.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(3);});
c4.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(4);});
c5.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(5);});
c6.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(6);});
c7.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(7);});
c8.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(8);});
c9.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(9);});
c10.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(10);});
c11.addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(11);});
```

Thanks for help - still learning :)

Comment: You could simplify your code a lot if you C was an array, and then you could have any number of values and use loops to do most of the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you can do this in one loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   document.getElementById('k'+i).addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(i);});
}
```

Comment: JSLint (2)
3 
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let'. for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
3 
Stopping. (4% scanned). for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 ESLint (1)
3 
ERROR: Parsing error: Unexpected token i for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Comment: It's missing a dot after the getElementById().

Comment: Thanks @user3489204.. fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('HTMLtag')

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {revealCard(i)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you're looking for:

Here I've created an array of the `k` values and then looped them with the click function:

```js
var kArray = ['k0','k1','k2','k3','k4','k5','k6','k7','k8','k9','k10','k11'];

kArray.forEach(function(item, i){
document.getElementById(item).addEventListener("click", function(){reavelCard(i);})
});

function reavelCard(num) {
console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<button id="k0">K0 Button</button>
<button id="k1">K1 Button</button>
<button id="k2">K2 Button</button>
<button id="k3">K3 Button</button>
<button id="k4">K4 Button</button>
<button id="k5">K5 Button</button>
<button id="k6">K6 Button</button>
<button id="k7">K7 Button</button>
<button id="k8">K8 Button</button>
<button id="k9">K9 Button</button>
<button id="k10">K10 Button</button>
<button id="k11">K11 Button</button>
```

Comment: I need something much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Ritesh answer works fine but if that doen't work you can try using JQuery.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   $('#k'+i).on("click", function(){reavelCard(i);});
}
```

Comment: @Ritesh solution wored for me after finding other error that I didn't see :P Checked yours and it works too good. Thanks :) How do I close this feed first timer :P